# Update datos en sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Tengo el Siguiente codigo, quisiera saber como modificarlo para hacer un update a los datos que consulto de la tabla id_rol_tercero, la tabla que deseo actualizar se llama rol_por_tercero,

```
use NameDatabase
SELECT  
    rol_por_tercero.id_tercero, 
    rol_por_tercero.id_rol_tercero
FROM    
    rolprovedor 
INNER JOIN      
    rol_por_tercero 
ON  
    rolprovedor.id_tercero = rol_por_tercero.id_tercero
```

Comment: necesitaríamos saber qué columna quieres actualizar y qué valor quieres ponerle

Comment: deseo actualizar la columna id_rol_tercero de la tabla rol_por_tercero

Comment: la tabla no se llama id_rol_tercero ese es un campo segun se ve en el select, redacta bien la pregunta y coloca los datos que solicita lamak

Comment: la tabla se llama rol_por_tercero, el campo que quiero actualizar se llama id_rol_tercero

Comment: en cuanto al valor es 4, @Lamak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para MS SQL Server seria:

```
UPDATE ROL
SET ROL.id_rol_tercero = 4 -- Valor a actualizar
FROM rol_por_tercero ROL
    INNER JOIN roprovedor PVR on PVR.id_tercero = ROL.id_tercero
--Si tienes un filtro adicional usa un WHERE aqui con la condicion
```

Comment: Perfecto, me ha funcionado muchas gracias